# How to make a regexp return all possibilities?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a CSV which columns can be 0, 1, or empty. Say that one row has this:

```
0,1,,,,1,0
```

I would like to extract the all possibilities of the "[01],+[01]" regexp, namely:

```
0,1
1,0
1,,,,1
```

Unfortunately, that regexp only returns me 0,1 and 1,0 because the "1"s can't be "reused" by another match.

Is it possible to do something like this using a regexp? It would be great if you could answer using grep's regexp style, but any (that works on Linux) will do.

Comment: If I understand your question cocrrectly, this should do the job `([01]?,)*[01]`

Comment: That wouldn't work, Zereges, because it'll also match the string "0". It also matches the entire test string "0,1,,,,1,0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with grep or pcregrep because the pattern you need must use a lookahead and you need to extract a capture group and not the whole match.

The fact is that you can't obtain several whole matchs from the same position in the string or with already consumed characters (because the regex engine always goes forward and makes new attempts after the last matched character ). So the trick is to use a zero-width assertion in which you put a capture group (the zero-width assertion doesn't consume characters, it's only a test):

```
(?=([01],+[01]))
```

Unfortunately, `pcregrep` is unable to return something else than the whole match, so you need to use Perl or any other language to obtain the capture group content.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eG9tR2/1)